# Add key value inside the multiple object array

Tags: javascript, angular

```
Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object ]

Object {
  id : 1,
  name : xyz,
  section : b
},{
  id : 2,
  name : abc,
  section : a
},

$scope.array = Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object ];

          angular.forEach$scope.array, function(value, key){
              $scope.array.push({
                'new_va' : 1
              })
          }
```

How can i add new key value for each object please guide
I tried different way but does not work Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
var arr = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'xyz',
    section: 'b'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'abc',
    section: 'a'
}];

arr.forEach(ele => ele.new_va = 1);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
$scope.array.forEach(function(obj, key){
    obj['new_va'] = 1;
})
```

Comment: This is the right way to do, I believe because it wont break any references. I am right?

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and `Object.assign`

```
var output = arr.map( s => Object.assign( s, s, { 'new_va' : 1 } ) )
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [{
  id : 1,
  name : "xyz",
  section : "b"
},{
  id : 2,
  name : "abc",
  section : "a"
}]
var output = arr.map( s => Object.assign( s, s, { 'new_va' : 1 } ) );

console.log(output);
```